# Why does the PayPal API sandbox environment return different states for create payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When creating a payment using the PayPal REST API's Sandbox environment, the response includes a `state` property of either: `created` or `approved`. This is true even with the same request payload, using the same test credit card.

Whereas in the Live environment, the response's `state` property is consistently `approved` on success.

The endpoint being used is [`POST /v1/payments/payment`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create).

Since we're using the PayPal REST API to process credit cards directly, and never sending users to paypal.com, the `state` property should always return `approved` or `failed` [per the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create).

Answer (score 1):

According to PayPal's technical support:

> I have consult our senior engineer and below are the justification.
>
> The reason why you are seeing sometime state = created or approved because that is the nature of a sandbox. In Live account, the state result constantly show as approve because it is already validate by the bank. Whereby, in sandbox it is not validate because we are using a fake credit card and that is the reason why we are responding inconsistence result of created or approved. This is to cater the result of both situation from the Live account. This happen since the fake credit card was not been approved in by the bank due to testing purposes. I hope this justify the issue.

In a nutshell: PayPal's Sandbox environment *intentionally* returns a random value for `state`, even though the value may not make sense for your app's payment flow.